# In JavaScript, can you use apply with Args?

Tags: javascript

Apply takes two arguments, a context, and the second argument is an array of arguments.  However, in JavaScript, args is not not an array, but "an array-like object".  So considering that it is not a true array is the following code valid:

```
function firstFunc(){
    secondFunc.apply(someContext,arguments);
}
```

Or do I need to through this ceremony:

```
function firstFunc(){
    var realArray=array.prototype.slice(arguments);
    secondFunc.apply(someContext,realArray);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you mean `arguments` not `args`. The first version is fine. MDN makes this quite clear [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Description) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply#Parameters):

> You can also use arguments for the argsArray parameter.

`argsArray` can be an array like object.

Note that until ES5, arguments was an exception to the rule and you couldn't use apply with other Array-like objects. In modern Javascript engines you can use apply with *any* Array-like object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` with `arguments`, without calling `slice`. I do this all the time.

As far as I know, there is nothing special about the word `args` in JavaScript.

Comment: Ah, but there is something special about `arguments`.  It's not a true array.  But yes, you can use `apply` with it just fine.

Comment: @Brad: You mean `arguments`? `args` isn't anything.

Comment: @Brad: Just to clarify: I think the OP understood that `arguments` isn't a true array. It's in the question itself. I was pointing out that `args` isn't special.